# Firebase storage: should I delete artifacts files in my firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have understood that each time i deploy a firebase cloud function, firebase automatically save some data in firebase storage. I would like to know excatly which data is saved and if it is safe to delete, or any suggestion on what to deleate.

I have a small project with 200MB of cloud storage used for user data and 10 cloud functions doing a variety of task. At the begining of October, I did few firebase deploy action and now I see a whooping 900MB of us.artifacts data. See below the screeneshot from firebase and google cloud. It looks like I have 256 items there with a mysterious .dms extension (disk image) and I really do not understand what this exaclty is, if i need to keep it or not.

I am currently considering to remove all these file and run a fresh firebase deploy but not sure if this is going to create any problem

Many thanks to anyone who can shine a bit of light here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I am currently considering to remove all these file and run a fresh firebase deploy but not sure if this is going to create any problem" Nope, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can remove the files and that would not cause any issues.